# How to implement Image Fusion Equation in Python

Tags: deep-learning, python, image-processing

I am new to image processing. I am trying to implement this paper. (official implementation is available on github the link for the same is given below) I have applied one fusion strategy. I am not able to apply the following equation in PyTorch.

[image]

The link to the paper and the GitHub is given below.

Link to paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.08361.pdf

Link to official implementation on GitHub:
https://github.com/hli1221/imagefusion_densefuse

Can someone please help me with this implementation?

Just the explanation of equation in relation with official implementation is also fine

Comment: Are you trying to implement [this](https://github.com/hli1221/imagefusion_densefuse/blob/master/fusion_l1norm.py) operation in PyTorch?

Comment: @LucaAnzalone Yes. I tried myself, but code is incorrect. I am getting blank images as a result

Comment: I see. Have you tried their pytorch version, [here](https://github.com/hli1221/densefuse-pytorch)? Also, I think you should post an issue on their github: you may receive better support.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help @LucaAnzalone